# Can I use a timer component in a WinForms Form to check the state of radio buttons and enable/disable a button?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

My small windows form application has two radio buttons, and initially neither is checked.  Until one of them is checked, the "Go" button should be disabled.

I found a very simple way to obtain this, but I'm not sure if I'm setting myself up for a random crash.

I added a timer component, enabled it, and in the Tick event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool canGo = (_usRadioButton.Checked || _intlRadioButton.Checked);
    if (_goButton.Enabled != canGo)
    {
        _goButton.Enabled = canGo;
    }
}
```

I know there are other ways to do this, I'm just curious if this way is valid or if I'm going to have an end user throwing exceptions when the timer is firing at the same time the form is updating the Checked property on one of the checkboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you already know about the CheckedChanged event, and are only asking about conflicts in your code. So:

As far as I know it's not multithreading, and there's no danger. The Tick event will actually not fire at the same time the computer is updating the Checked state.

If you place traces in Form.Load and Timer.Tick:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Form_Load/Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId=" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Console.WriteLine("timer1_Tick/Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId=" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}
```

The results show:

```
Form_Load/Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId=9
timer1_Tick/Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId=9
```

Comment: OK, you're saying that the Tick event is on the form's thread, which is probably the question I should have asked (I was thinking it).

Comment: Yes. But that's only "As far as I know". Perhaps you're better off waiting for [Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) or [Hans](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) to answer that for sure.

Comment: I believe I verified your answer with traces - i'm going to edit it to include this (hope thats OK, if not just kill it)

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is to subscribed to the CheckedChanged event of your radio buttons and then enable the "Go" button in that event handler.

This will solve any timing problems you will encounter with this approach.

Comment: thanks, you made me realize it's the same code that way - however, do you agree there less "de-coupled-ness" to it?  I could be wrong about that...

Comment: @Gabriel - I think the "coupledness" is the same in either approach. You need to read the values of the radio buttons to set the enabled state of the button.

Comment: This is good perspective for me, as I wasn't even thinking of the Checked properties - I was regarding the subscription to the CheckChanged event of two radio buttons as worse than the Tick event of a timer, combined with the fact that the timer has not direct relationship to the form... maybe my flaw is regarding events as a "coupling" factor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that it's safer, but you could also subscribe to the CheckedChanged event and use that handler code to enable the Go button.  This would save you a timer that would have to run indefinitely.